# querying a database to populate a table

Tags: php

I'm new to web applications, I was trying to write this simple query

```
$query2 = "SELECT * from sections WHERE  starting = ' 8:00 ' And day = ' Monday ' AND section = '$section' AND campus = '$campus' AND year = '$year'  ";

$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error($conn));
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count2==0){
    echo'<td color=orange>&nbsp;</td>';
    }
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>".$row['course']."</td>";}
```

However I'm getting this error. I tried to figure it out but I couldn't. Could someone plz help me

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'And day = ' Monday ' AND section = 'A' AND campus = 'Nabatieh'
>   AND year = 'Bache' at line 1

Comment: `year = 'Bache'`? sure? My guess is, year is defined as int (for a good reason), but you pass a string

Comment: Also, you're mixing mysql and mysql. That won't work. Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: If my first comment didn't point you to the error you've got, you'd need to show: how/where `$year` is defined and your table-definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL server is not entertaining case insensitive query designs . I mean it is differentiating between And & AND ... So i suggest modifying your query like..
    $query2 = "SELECT * from sections WHERE starting = ' 8:00 ' AND day = ' Monday ' AND section = '$section' AND campus = '$campus' AND year = '$year' ";

Comment: If so, then Please bother to show your database table design because I think you are probably sending a string value to the database instead of an integer or something...

Answer (score 0):

Dude, another possibility is that you didn't give a space after the first value before And... Do double check on it please...

Because the error shown has displayed 'And ...  Instead... it should be ' And ....

Answer (score -2):

It could be the "And" after the "starting" var is in upper and lower. Although Mysql is not necessarily case sensitive, you shouldn't mix upper and lower.

see here...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html